# Alberto Bressan chapter 3 question 1. Showing closure of a family of functions is equal to the space it is contained in

Tags: functional-analysis

I appologise for the awkward title. This may have already been asked, but I am not sure how I would search such a question, anyway here is my question, vertabim from Alberto Bressan (Lecture notes of functional analysis and PDE's)

The question:
Let $E$ be a compact metric space. Assume that a family of real valued continuous functions $\mathcal{F}\subset C(E ;\mathbb{R})$ satisfies the following two conditions

i) for every $x,y\in E$ and $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a function $f\in \mathcal{F}$ such that $f(x)=a$ and $f(y)=b$.

ii) If $f,g \in \mathcal{F}$, the functions $\operatorname{max}\{f,g\}$ and $\operatorname{min}\{f,g\}$ lie in the closure $\overline{\mathcal{F}}$

Prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is dense in $C(E ;\mathbb{R})$

My attempt:

$\mathcal{F} \subset C(E; \mathbb{R})$ and hence $\overline{\mathcal{F}}\subset \overline{C(E; \mathbb{R})}=C(E;\mathbb{R})$ since $C(E; \mathbb{R})$ is closed. Now we seek to show the reverse inclusion which will show that $\mathcal{F}$ is dense in $C(E ;\mathbb{R})$.

Consider $f\in C(E; \mathbb{R})$. Choose points $x_1,x_2 \in E$ and let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be $f(x_1)$ ,$f(x_2)$ respectively. We then, by (i) know that there exists a function $f_{1}\in \mathcal{F}$ that satisfies $f_1(x_1)=y_1$ and $f_2(x_2)=y_2$.

In a similar fashion we can choose points $x_3$ and $x_4$ in $E$ and let $y_3=f(x_3)$ and $y_4=f(x_4)$ and by (i) again know that there exists a a function $f_{2}\in \mathcal{F}$ such that $f_2(x_3)=y_3$ and $f_2(x_4)=y_4$.

It is at this stage I attempt to use condition (ii) to help me. I know that $\operatorname{max}\{f_1,f_2\}$ and $\operatorname{min}\{f_1,f_2\}$ being in $\overline{\mathcal{F}}$ imply that there are a sequence of functions in $\mathcal{F}$ which converge to $\operatorname{max}\{f_1,f_2\}$ and $\operatorname{min}\{f_1,f_2\}$ but this doesn't seem to help me in creating a sequence of functions which converge to $f$.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use the Stone-Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: But how do we know $\mathcal{F}$ is a subalgebra of $C(E,\mathbb{R})$? if $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are in $\mathcal{F}$ then what makes $f_{1}+f_{2}$ in $\mathcal{F}$ and how do I know the other properties for a subalgebra are satisfied? All we are told is that $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of functions.